# C# Convert Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, generic-type-argument

I have 2 classes:

```
abstract class Bar { }

class Foo<T> where T : Bar { }
```

and I want to to create a List of 'Foo's that can have different generic classes that are all inherited from 'Bar':

```
class NewBar : Bar { }
```

But I can not save the classes as `Foo<Bar>`:

```
Foo<Bar> variable = new Foo<NewBar>();
```

So what have I done wrong and how would this be possible?

Comment: `Foo` needs to be co-variant for this to work, which is `class Foo<out T> where ...`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/ for further details.

Comment: What have you tried? There are tens, if not hundreds of questions that describe this. Keywords being "covariance" and "contravariance".